# HTML getting data from and to servlet (School Project Question)

Tags: gwt, servlets

So I am working on a group project for school. I was responsible for the database portion of the project. We have a working database and I wrote some Data Access Objects to access the data from the DB.

Another portion of the group is writing the front-end of the servlet and will also be writing some HTML pages that are going to make requests to and display information from the servlet.

A few members of our group are in favor of using GWT to help connect the front-end of the server to the clients.

My question is whether this is a good way to go about solving this problem. The only sort of web development I am used to is ASP.net with C# code-behinds, so I am at a bit of a loss.

So, any advice or tips would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure we would be willing to look into most anything, but since the project is due fairly soon, the less steep the learning curve the better.

Comment: Are you using an IDE in your group?  Like Eclipse or Netbeans?

Comment: @Dave we are writing the servlet in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While GWT is a great library; I think its overkill for what you're looking for.  [Here is a youtube video I always default to when I need to get a review on how to set up a quick tomcat instance](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOkN5IPoJVs).  It is using an older version of eclipse, and while some of the menu options are slightly different you should be able to figure it out.  If you see something in the video and you can't figure it out in the newer version of eclipse, just let me know what time in the video you're getting lost at and I'll post how to do it in the helios (the newer version of Eclipse).

Also, this video uses Tomcat which is a servlet container.  I'd go ahead and use Tomcat 7, which uses servlets 3.0.  If your assignment requires an earlier version, then you should be able to figure out which version of Tomcat contains that version and use that.

To be honest, the only reason I'm pushing Tomcat here is because of how easy I know it is to setup from my own personal experience, especially from within Eclipse.  So there are other options out there if you want to take the time to research them (ie Jetty); but this is what I know so its what I'm recommending.

Comment: Thank you sir. We are fairly familiar with Tomcat, so I will definitely check out the video. I appreciate your offer to provide additional help and I will add a new comment if anything is not clear.